# conditional format while update Excel Workbook using vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, conditional-formatting

I have a Problem while updating my Excel Workbook with vb.net.

Basically I will create a timetable in Excel. So at my first line in Excel I have on each cell a date.

[This is my Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyNVP.png)

For Cells `C2` to `I2` I have a conditional format with a formula:

```
=AND(C$1>=$A2;C$1<=$B2)
```

This works great. When I change the value of `B2` using vb.net    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

```
    Dim ExcelFolder As String
    Dim selectedfile As String
    Dim excel As Application
    Dim workbook As Workbook
    Dim sheet As Worksheet

    ExcelFolder = "C:\temp"

    selectedfile = ExcelFolder & "\" & "test.xlsx"
    excel = New Application
    excel.Workbooks.Open(selectedfile)
    workbook = excel.ActiveWorkbook
    sheet = workbook.Worksheets(2)

    'change value on B2
    sheet.Cells(2, 2) = "07.10.2017"

    workbook.SaveAs("test.xlsx", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, False, False, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
    workbook.Close()
    excel.Quit()
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel) : excel = Nothing
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook) : workbook = Nothing
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet) : sheet = Nothing
```

It will change the value, but the background wouldn't change. I have to go manually to cell `B2` and press ENTER again, after that the conditional format will work.   I have tried to write a Date to the cell or change the cell format before and after inserting to Date, without success. I also tried to add a conditional format with vb.net after inserting the new data, without any success. Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the [EnableCalculation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._worksheet.enablecalculation.aspx) property on your Worksheet object is set to true:

```
sheet.EnableCalcuation = True
sheet.Cells(2, 2) = "07.10.2017"
```

Comment: The EnableCalculation property is true, but the conditional formatting won't work.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if calling sheet.Calculate() (after applying values) will trigger the conditional formatting.